# file_get_contents returns an empty string

Tags: php

I am sending this json to my php site (http://example.com/webhook/) as a post from a third-party site, but all I get is an empty array.

```
{
  "listing_id": 0,
  "guest_id": 0,
  "confirmation_code": "confirmation code",
  "start_date": "2015-05-05",
  "nights": 1,
  "number_of_guests": 3,
  "listing_base_price": 399
}
```

And for this, I am using the following server-side code in the index.php file:

```
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
echo $json;
$data = json_decode($json, True);
```

The response is expected to be json so I am unable to use var_dump() hence it returns other than json.

Comment: How are you sending this to the PHP script?

Comment: `var_dump($json)`, see what's really there. `f_g_c()` returns boolean false on failure.

Comment: `var_dump($json)` will also work if the data is not JSON. It doesn't really matter what the output is - var_dump() will show even "null" data. One of my favourite features of PHP, actually :)